# Display moving blocks in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that creates a JFrame on which a simple game of Tetris will be played, I also have a class DrawSquare, which does exactly what you think it does, however when I initialise a new instance of the DrawSquare class and then try to draw that one and all the others to my JFrame things start to go wrong, the code is intended for one square to be drawn in the top left hand corner and then drop down a line at a time until it reaches the bottom of the frame (it does this), then a new square should be drawn in the second column at the top of the frame, as well as our first square in the bottom left hand corner, however once it starts dropping down the second column I get a series of squares drawn in a diagonal towards the top right hand corner. At the moment all I plan for the code to do is have a square drop from the top row of each column and stop when it reaches the bottom of the frame, am I storing the instance of the class at the wrong point in the code? Edit: In fact I'm pretty sure it's that, I'd want to store that instance when it reaches the bottom. Does every instance of the class need its own timer?

```
public class Tetris extends JFrame {
    public static final int height = 20; //height of a square
    public static final int width = 20; //width of a square
    public int xPos = 0; //column number of the square
    public int yPos = 0; //row number of the square

    public static void main(String[] args){
            Tetris tet = new Tetris();
    }

    public Tetris() {
        DrawSquare square = new DrawSquare(xPos, yPos, width, height, false);
        add(square);
        DrawSquare.squares.add(square);
        setSize(220,440);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}


public class DrawSquare extends JPanel {
    public static List<DrawSquare> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    protected int xPos;
    protected int yPos;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected Timer timer = new Timer(200, new TimerListener());
    protected boolean endFall = false;


    public DrawSquare(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, boolean endFall) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.endFall = endFall;
        this.timer.start();
    }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            yPos++;
            if (yPos > 19) {
                yPos = 19;
                endFall = true;
            }
            if (endFall == true) {
                timer.stop();
                if (xPos > 8) {
                    xPos = 8;
                }
                xPos++;
                endFall = false;
                yPos = 0;
                DrawSquare newSqr = new DrawSquare(xPos, yPos, width, height, true);
                squares.add(newSqr);
                add(newSqr);
            }
            timer.start();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Iterator<DrawSquare> it = squares.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            DrawSquare square = it.next();
            g.fillRect(square.xPos * square.width, square.yPos * square.height, square.width, square.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how else to say this, but you are mashing a lot of swing concepts together very incorrectly. I will draft an answer, but it will take a few minutes.

Comment: Well how could I separate them out so that I'm not using them incorrectly? Would appreciate a draft answer I've really hit a wall in terms of working round this myself (probably because I'm mashing things together incorrectly like you said)

Comment: I'm finishing up.

Comment: Why are you calling `timer.start()` from within the timer's own ActionListener?

Comment: Heh. I didn't even pay attention to that.

Comment: Lol. I don't know, I made a mess and that just worked.

Comment: I have been working with languages other than Java for about a year now, so if you find errors in my answer, please feel free to correct them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: (1+) for the magnum opus effort, posted as I posted my (*very* short) answer. Now let me go through it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. Please do. I have used this as a vehicle to remove some of the dust off of my Java. I would appreciate any criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving a great example of the fundamental misunderstanding beginners have of how the swing (and many other graphics toolkits) render stuff to the screen. I will give an overview of that, as it pertains to you, then answer your immediate questions and explain how to fix your code.

It took me a (very long) while to figure out how this stuff works my self, so please bear with me. I hope that reading through this answer will help you in a much more general way than answering this one question.

### Asynchronous Drawing

Swing draws windows in a totally different sequence (the event dispatching thread) than the ones that modifies the state of your program (the main thread, as well as timer and other threads). You can modify the coordinates of things you want to draw as many times as you like in the main thread, but the changes will not show up until you request them to by calling `JComponent.repaint()` on one of your components. This will generally trigger a nearly-immediate repaint of the component, displaying your latest state.

If you change the coordinates of a widget like a `JPanel` in your main thread, it will likely show up immediately. This is because the methods you use to set the position will trigger repaint requests internally.

A repaint request gets queued and eventually processed by the event dispatching thread. This is where the `paintComponent` method gets called. The `paintComponent` method should therefore only draw. It should not do any other logic. If it needs to know how to draw some specialized stuff, the information for that should be stashed somewhere accessible by one of the other threads.

In short, you make calculations and update state as you need in the main thread or the timer. Then you access that state in the event dispatching thread via the `paintComponent` method.

### Timers

There are a bunch of ways you can use timers to run your GUI, but you only really need one for the current application. In your case, the timer only needs to do two things:

1. Check if a block has fallen all the way down and doesn't need to move any more.
2. Trigger a repaint of your panel.

You do *not* need to compute the updated position of the blocks in the timer if the block's position is a simple equation with respect to time. If you know the time at which a block appears on the screen and the current time, you know how far the block has moved, so you can paint it in the correct spot based purely on the elapsed time.

If you had a more complicated system with paths that you could not predict purely on the time, I would recommend sticking the movement logic into the timer events as well. In that case, you might consider having multiple timers, or switching to `java.util.timer`. But again, this does not apply to your current case (even with multiple blocks).

### Model and View

The model of your program is the thing that holds the abstract state. In this case, the positions and other meta-data about all your blocks. The view is the part that does the rendering. It is usually a good idea to separate these two things. There is often a third component to GUIs, called the controller, which connects the model and view to the user. We will ignore it here since you are not asking about controlling the blocks yet.

In your current code, you have attempted to represent your blocks with an extension to `JPanel` and a `static` list of existing blocks. While a `JPanel` may be a convenient way to display rectangular blocks with some custom graphics in them (like icons), I would recommend that you start by drawing the blocks directly using the `Graphics` object passed to `paintComponent`. At least initially, it will help you to think of the drawing code and the game logic as separate entities.

### Final Rant Before Code Dump

I have made rewrites to your code to encapsulate all the ranting I did before into code. Here are some additional minor points about what I did that may help explain my reasoning:

- When you call `JFrame.add(...)` to add a component to a `JFrame`, you are really calling `JFrame.getContentPane().add(...)`. The content pane is where 90% of normal swing components go in a window. Therefore, we can either set the `JPanel` that will do the rendering as your content pane or we can add it to the current content pane. I have chosen to do the latter so that you can add other widgets, like a score board, at a later time.
- Class names should generally be nouns, while methods are often verbs. This is not an absolute rule (nothing really is), but naming things this way will often help you visualize the interactions between objects in a more meaningful way. I have renamed `DrawSquare` to `GamePiece` for this reason.
- There is no longer any reason for `GamePiece` to be a `JPanel`. It just needs to know its own width, height, and time of appearance.
- The other problem with trying to have `DrawSquare` draw itself is that a component can only really draw within its own bounding box. So you really want to override the `paintComponent` of whatever holds the rectangles.
- The rendering class maintains a reference to two lists of `GamePiece`s. One is for the moving objects and one is for the ones that have fallen. The logic for moving them between the lists is in the timer. This is better than say adding a flag to `GamePiece` because it facilitates incremental repaint. I will only partially illustrate this here, but there is a version of repaint that only requests a small region to be painted. This would be useful to speed up the movement.

### Code

```
public class Tetris extends JFrame
{
    public static final int height = 20; //height of a square
    public static final int width = 20; //width of a square
    public static final int x = 0;

    private GamePanel gamePanel;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tetris tet = new Tetris();
        // Normally you would tie this to a button or some other user-triggered action.
        tet.gamePanel.start();
        tet.gamePanel.addPiece(new GamePiece(width, height, x));
    }

    public Tetris()
    {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gamePanel = GamePanel();
        add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(220,440);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    private List<GamePiece> moving;
    private List<GamePiece> still;
    private Timer timer;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        moving = new ArrayList<>();
        still = new ArrayList<>();
        timer = new Timer(100, new TimerListener());
    }

    public addPiece(int width, int height, int x)
    {
        moving.add(new GamePiece(width, height, x));
    }

    public void start()
    {
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle clip = g.getClipBounds(null);
        Rectangle rectToDraw = new Rectangle();

        // I prefer this, but you can make the call every
        // time you call `GamePiece.getY()`
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(GamePiece piece : this.moving) {
            rectToDraw.setSize(piece.width, piece.height)
            rectToDraw.setLocation(piece.x, piece.getY(time))
            if(rectangleToDraw.intersects(clip))
                ((Graphics2D)g).fill(rectToDraw)
        }

        for(GamePiece piece : this.still) {
            rectToDraw.setSize(piece.width, piece.height)
            rectToDraw.setLocation(piece.x, piece.getY(time))
            if(rectangleToDraw.intersects(clip))
                ((Graphics2D)g).fill(rectToDraw)
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // Using non-iterator loop to move the pieces that
            // stopped safely. Iterator would crash on in-loop move.
            for(int i = 0; i < moving.size(); i++) {
                piece = moving.get(i);
                if(piece.getY(time) > 440 - piece.height) {
                    moving.remove(i);
                    still.add(piece);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

public class GamePiece
{
    public final int width;
    public final int height;
    public final long startTime;
    public int x;

    public GamePiece(int width, int height, int x)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY(long time)
    {
        // This hard-codes a velocity of 10px/sec. You could
        // implement a more complex relationship with time here.
        return (int)((time - this.startTime) / 100.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue -- `paintComponent` should *never* be declared `synchronized`. For one, there's no need since Swing is single threaded.

Comment: Swing is, but my timer modifies the lists that it uses to get the state. Since it uses an iterator, it has to be synchronized.

Comment: Also, nothing else needs to be synchronized since all the main code is again being run within a single thread, the Swing Event Dispatch Thread, or EDT. In fact, your program should take pains to create itself on this thread by use of the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` method call.

Comment: Regarding your comment -- again not true. The iterator, the Timer, are all run on a single thread. Period.

Comment: Ah. I was not aware of the fact that the swing timer ran on EDT. I just kinda assumed that it subclassed or used util.Timer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Fixed.

Comment: I see. It does use another thread to fire the events most likely, but the events are processed on EDT. Very interesting.

Comment: Of yes, of course a Swing Timer must do its timing in another thread, and its API will mention this, but the key benefit to this construct is that it's guaranteed to call its ActionListener's code on the event thread.

Comment: Like I said, rusty and dusty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation.

Comment: @Chaz. No problem. I hope it works out for you and helps you mentally declutter your thoughts about GUIs. They are pretty confusing at first, but like everything else, they become fairly easy to work with once you have the right mental model.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem in a nutshell: you need to separate the JPanel component class from the square logical class. Right now, they are one and the same, and every time you create a new DrawSqaure, you're creating a new JPanel, starting a new Swing Timer, and thus calling code that doesn't need to be called. This is also forcing you to make the List static else you'd have a stack overflow error. Solution: separate the two out, make your List non-static, and use only one Swing Timer.